# I lost all my progress on Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

I accidentally pressed sign out on Pokemon Go while I was in town, I signed back in and it then showed the screen for "Server down". I turned my phone on half an hour later and then it asked me to authenticate my account again which I did, which reset my account... I went back to Level 1 with no Pokemon

What do I do to get back my progress?!

Comment: You may have created a new account and lost your previous one.

Answer (score 2):

- Are you sure you signed in with the same account you made it with?
- Perhaps try again later, might be server issues.
- Also try contacting [niantic support](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this thread:
https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/224047008

Looks like you should uninstall and reinstall the app.  Appears to be a known iOS bug.
A friend of mine went out of the country for a month and returned to find this identical problem.

Scroll down to:

> iOS users: Progress appears to be reset after updating Pokémon GO
>
> In the Pokémon GO update version 0.31.0, we updated our Google Account > login system and as a result, you may have inadvertently created another Pokémon GO account by logging in with a different Google email address than the one originally used for the game.
>
> To resolve this issue: please follow the steps below to sign in with the email address originally used to create your Pokémon GO account.
>
> 1) Uninstall the Pokémon GO app.
>   2) Reinstall the Pokémon GO app from the App Store.
>   3) Open Pokémon GO and select the Google login method.

Note, their site lists a few more steps, but basically uninstall app, reinstall and then make sure you are picking the same Google account you made your first account with, even if the bug created a 2nd account with that same Google account.